# Trouble with input accepting a space from a pointer

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to accept spaces in my name char, but every time I run the program after inputting (asked in int main) how many scores I would like to input it bugs out and prompts two inputs at the same time. Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

```
void readData(vector<Highscore>& scores)
{
    //Local integer variable used to update user #
    int index = 0;

    //For loop iterator that stores user input and name
    for(vector<Highscore>::iterator i = scores.begin(); i != scores.end(); i++)
    {
        //Prompts user for name
        cout << "Enter the name for score #" << (index + 1) << ": ";
        cin.getline(i->name,'\n');
        //cin >> i->name;

        //Prompts user for their score
        cout << "Enter the score for score #" << (index + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> i->score;

        //Keeps track of the index and updates it everytime it iterates
        index++;
    } 
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Before a call of getline insert this statement std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

Answer (score 1):

After this statement

```
cin >> i->score;
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

So the next call of `std::getline` reads an empty string.

You need to remove it  before calling `std::getline`.

You can do it inserting this statement

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

after this statement

```
cin >> i->score;
```

To do so you need to include the header

```
#include <limits>
```

Try this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;
    char c;
    
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, s );
        std::cout << s << '\n';
        
        std::cout << "Continue ('y' to continue)? ";
        std::cin >> c;
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    } while ( c == 'y' || c == 'Y' );
    
    return 0;
}
```